# Android, Save ArrayList for when reopening app

Tags: android

I'm creating an app wich is supposed to do the following:
- When started shows a splash/info-activity.
- In next activity shows a list of names as checkboxes
- user can add new names via EditText & Add-button (list updated dynamically)
- When closing app, and reopening, names previously added should be saved and displayed in list.
I've tried to setup my list as ArrayList in my startingactivity just to see if I can save and load my information correctly:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Typeface face;
TextView tvStartIntrotext;
Button bStartStart;

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

String NAMESFILE = "names_file";
FileOutputStream fos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.startactivity);

    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "andalemono.ttf");
    bStartStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStartStart);
    bStartStart.setTypeface(face);
    tvStartIntrotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStartIntrotext);
    tvStartIntrotext.setTypeface(face);
    bStartStart.setOnClickListener(this);

    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(NAMESFILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        names.add("Name Name");
        oos.writeObject(names);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.startactivity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, Choose.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
}
}
```

To read and display I have this in my other activity so far:

```
public class Choose extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String NAMESFILE = "names_file";
FileInputStream fis;

Button bChooseChoose, bChooseAdd;
Typeface face;
TextView tvChoosePick;
EditText etChooseAddnew;
LinearLayout llMain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slideinright, R.anim.slideoutleft);
    setContentView(R.layout.choose);


    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "andalemono.ttf");
    bChooseChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bChooseChoose);
    bChooseChoose.setTypeface(face);
    bChooseChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    bChooseAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bChooseAdd);
    bChooseAdd.setTypeface(face);
    bChooseAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvChoosePick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChoosePick);
    tvChoosePick.setTypeface(face);
    etChooseAddnew = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etChooseAddnew);
    etChooseAddnew.setTypeface(face);
    etChooseAddnew.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white1);
    etChooseAddnew.setHintTextColor(color.greytext);
    llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMain);


    try {
        fis = openFileInput(NAMESFILE);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ArrayList<Object> names = (ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject();            

        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        CheckBox cbb = new CheckBox(this);
        cbb.setText(names.get(i));
        cbb.setTypeface(face);
        cbb.setTextSize(16);
        llMain.addView(cbb);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bChooseChoose:

        break;
    case R.id.bChooseAdd:

                   /*This button for adding new list name*/

        break;
    }

    }
}
```

One error I'm getting at this point is "setText" in my for-loop. Don't yet know how to get the information from the file opened to display in a list correctly. Although the for-loop works when no fileInput/Output is used.
Any pointers to what I can try would be really helpful, since I'm new to Android programming. :)
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `names` variable declared inside `try-catch` block and cannot be accessed from outside. Just move declaration out of the block:

```
List<Object> names;
try {
    fis = openFileInput(NAMESFILE);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    names = (ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject();            
    ois.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    names = Collections.emptyList();
}
```

**UPDATE**
And you can't use `cbb.setText(names.get(i))` because `names.get(i)` is not a String. It's an object (that actually should be String if you saved strings in `NAMESFILE`).
You can either case it to String:

```
cbb.setText((String)names.get(i))
```

or use `toString` method:

```
cbb.setText(names.get(i).toString())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Follow-up question: I realize that I had som sort of problem with the names variable since I first declared it in my first activity. This helped me make "names" declared again I think. However, the error with "setText" in my second activity remains, which is my way of checking if output/input works ;). Is there an easier way to check this maybe?

Comment: The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (Object) - is the message.

Comment: That fixed the error, and it seems to work when running app! (after commenting out Collections.emptyList(); which I will have to read about ;)

Seems my only problem right now is making sure that the file doesn't reset when re-starting app. But hopefully I can figure that one out ;)
Thank you so much for your help!